# 1D array writing format

Tags: fortran

This is my code:

```
Program Array_Output

Implicit none

Integer :: i , Size_0
Integer , allocatable :: Array_0 (:)
Character , parameter :: fmt_0 = '()' !How to get: 'size_0(1X,i3)'

Write(*,*)"Enter the number:"
Read(*,*) Size_0

Allocate(Array_0(Size_0))

Do i = 1 , Size_0

   Array_0(i) = i + 4

End Do

Open(Unit = 16, File='Output.txt', Status = 'Unknown', action = 'Write')

  Write(16, fmt_0 ) ( Array_0(i), i = 1 , Size_0)

Close(Unit = 16)

End Program Array_Output
```

My intention with this code is to write `output` format which contains entered number `Size_0`. How to write that number in format afther entering that number fom keyboard?

Comment: Please don't tag all the Fortran versions you can fit. If you need a specific Fortran version, use tag that one. If you can use anything that works in moderb versions, just tag Fortran. Not that the solution in the answer below (also contained in the links) is Fortran 2008 so does not conform to your tags.

Comment: Ok. Can you show me how to use, in this case, concatenation operator ‚`//` ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Use it for what? In which case?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether/when it became standard, but I use the format `(*(1X, I3))` for this.

If that doesn't work, you have to become more creative:

```
character(len=len('(___(1X, I3))')) :: fmt_0

...

write(fmt_0, '(A1, I3, A)') "(", size_0, "(1X,I3))"
write(16, fmt_0) Array(1:size_0)
```